# Angular Boostrap UI Modal pass custom close and dismiss functions to ModalInstanceCtrl?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a reusable ModalInstanceCtrl where I can pass custom OK and cancel functions along with any custom data. I am able to pass params where the values are not functions.

**In current Controller**

```
 $scope.showInterest = function(jobId) {

     var params = {
         animation: true,
         templateUrl: 'show-insert-modal.php',
         controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
         size: 'sm',
         resolve: {
             params: function() {
                 var params = {
                     // included in params OK
                     modalName: 'showInterest', 
                     jobId: jobId,
                     title: 'Show Interest',

                     //Not included in params
                     cancel: function() {
                         modalInstance.dismiss();
                     },
                     ok: function($modalScope) {
                         $modalScope.isSaving = true;
                         // some promise to run then
                         modalInstance.close()
                     }
                 };
                 return params;
             }
         }
     };


     var modalInstance = $modal.open(params);
 }
```

**ModalInstanceCtrl**

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'params',

    function($scope, $modalInstance, params) {


        function cancel(reason) {
            params.cancel(reason);
        }

        function ok() {
            //TypeError: params.ok is not a function
            params.ok($scope);
        };

        // properties with functions are not part of the params variable
        //console.log(params) = Object {modalName: "showInterest", jobId: 1907, title: "Show Interest"} 
        console.log(params);

        var scope = {
            isSaving: false,
            params: params,
            ok: ok,
            cancel: cancel
        };
        angular.extend($scope, scope);

    }
]);
```

Comment: `I am able to pass params where the values are not functions` --> What do you see then as?

Comment: @PSL console.log(params) = Object {modalName: "showInterest", jobId: 1907, title: "Show Interest"}

Comment: It should have your methods as well, no? try to isolate the problem alone and see if something else might be overwriting your properties. The code as is should work.

Comment: @PSL yes you are right the code does work indeed, I was calling the wrong function from my template where I have not set the OK and cancel functions yet. It's one of those days ;).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the *result* promise to call your methods. Below is a basic example:

```
crntPopup = $modal.open( tmpl )
crntPopup.result.then( function(){ yourCloseCallback()})
crntPopup.result.catch( function(){ yourDismissCallback()})
```

From the modal docs (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal):

> The open method returns a modal instance, an object with the following properties:
>
> - close(result) - a method that can be used to close a modal, passing a result
> - dismiss(reason) - a method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason
> - **result - a promise that is resolved when a modal is closed and rejected when a modal is dismissed**
> - opened - a promise that is resolved when a modal gets opened after downloading content's template and resolving all variables
> - rendered - a promise that is resolved when a modal is rendered.

Comment: I tried this approach the problem is in order to fire the close callback I have to call modalInstance.$close() which first closes the modal then fires the call back.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem then.  Are you saying that the problem is the fact that you must call `$close` to fire the call back **or** that the callback is executed *after* you call `$close` and you want it to do so *before* closing?  I'd say recreate this in a jsfiddle or plunker, then I can maybe be better equipped to help you.

Comment: Also to whoever downvoted this answer, this is indeed a valid solution which I have used and is recommended by the UI.Bootstrap docs.  Is there a particular reason it was downvoted or that you simply didn't like the answer?